# Schema Changes not Allowed on Delta Live Tables Full Refresh

Tags: pyspark, databricks, hive-metastore, aws-databricks, delta-live-tables

I have a simple Delta Live Tables pipeline that performs a streaming read of multiple csv files from cloudFiles (s3 storage) into a delta table published to the hive metastore.

I have two requirements that make my situation more complex/unique:

1. I need to use the `skipRows` parameter to autoLoader due to the format of the csv files. This necessitates using the preview channel of the Databricks runtime (v11.3 at the time of writing). [source](https://community.databricks.com/s/question/0D58Y00009e1BhLSAU/mapskiprows-1-ignored-during-autoloader-process-something-wrong-with-the-format)
2. I need to set the table `columnMapping.mode` property to `name` as the csv data has characters in column names that are not allowed natively by Delta / Parquet. [source](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/delta-column-mapping.html)

Both of the above seem to be preview/beta features, so perhaps the behavior I'm observing is a bug.

My pipeline is defined as follows:

```
import dlt
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *

s3_url = "s3://<path_to_csvs>"

@dlt.table(
    comment="...",
    table_properties={
        'delta.minReaderVersion' : '2', 
        'delta.minWriterVersion' : '5', 
        'delta.columnMapping.mode' : 'name',
        'quality': 'bronze'
    }
)
def bronze_my_csv_data_raw():
  return (
    spark.readStream.format("cloudFiles")
      .option("skipRows", 1)
      .option("header", "true")
      .option("cloudFiles.includeExistingFiles", "true")
      .option("cloudFiles.format", "csv")
      .option("cloudFiles.schemaEvolutionMode", "addNewColumns")
      .option("pathGlobFilter", "*.csv")
      .load(s3_url)
  )
```

This works as intended when the pipeline is set and run for the first time, but even without making any code changes, re-running a "Full refresh all" of the pipeline (to refresh all the data), gives the following error:

```
com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.DeltaColumnMappingUnsupportedException: 
Schema change is detected:

old schema:
root


new schema:
root
 |-- TIMESTAMP: string (nullable = true)
 |-- RECORD: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Samples_Max: string (nullable = true)
 ...

Schema changes are not allowed during the change of column mapping mode.
```

This happens even if I change the target table name to create a fresh, empty table. Once it has happened, the same error occurs even in a regular (not full refresh) run.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Have you tried with ```mergeSchema``` by any chance?

Comment: I don’t think it is possible to specify `mergeSchema` (or `overwriteSchema` for that matter) on a DLT table as the `.write` command is not explicit in the notebook (declarative syntax and all).
Instead, I have tried adding the spark config: `"spark.databricks.delta.schema.autoMerge.enabled": "true"` to both the table properties and the pipeline configuration (and cluster config), neither of which seems to change anything.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem. But the only special characters in my column names were spaces, so I just replaced them:

```
@dlt.table(name=table_name)
def table():
    df = spark.readStream.format("cloudFiles").options(**cloud_files_options).load(source)

    # Replace all spaces with underscores
    df = df.select([col(c).alias(c.replace(" ", "_")) for c in df.columns])

    return df
```

This is obviously not ideal because my raw table is no longer "raw", but at least I can recompute my entire pipeline from scratch now.

EDIT - don't forget to remove `columnMapping.mode` from your table properties if you decide to go down this route.